# How to run function from the end to the beginning?

Tags: jquery, animation

I wrote an animation which starts after klicking on a button in jquery. Now I want to run this animation from the end to the very beginning. Is this possible in jquery or I have to write this animation again but this time obverse? I mean just a back function which recreate every step and at the end looks like before clicking anything.

```
$( "#three" ).click(function() {
    $( "#two, #four, #five, #six" ).addClass( "animated out" );
    $( "#seven" ).addClass( "show" );
    $( "#three" ).addClass( "animated totheleft" );
    $( "#mytext" ).addClass( "animated totheright" );
    setTimeout(function(){$("#mytext").addClass("hide");},2000);
});
```

Comment: By the time you wrote this question down and submitted it to SO, you could have done it manually by now. ;D

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
$( "#two, #four, #five, #six" ).removeClass( "animated out" );
$( "#seven" ).removeClass( "show" );
... so on
},2000);
```

Comment: But this what you wrote doesn't recreate animation (animated out) just shows my objects again.

Comment: When you use setTimeout method you can call another function with backward animation.

Comment: but I don't want to write this function obverse.